# Sending multiple packets together in OMNET++ continuausly

Tags: omnet++

I am new to OMNET++ and need your help. I am working on a simulation where packets need to go from one module to another without waiting for first module to send all packets.

```
 -------------               ------------          -------------   
|   Module A  |     -->     |  Module B  |   -->  |   Module C  |
 -------------               ------------          -------------
```

Now if module A send 5 packets to Module C through Module B, Module B waiting for all 5 packets to receive, and after it receive all 5 packets than its start sending to Module C.

what I want is, if module B receive a packets, it needs to send straight away to Module C without waiting for Module A to send all packets.

Please check the attached image for your reference. in this image you can see that middle 4 modules keeping all the packets and starts forwarding when module 1 sends all packets.

[image]

thanks for your help in advance.

### Module A Code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace omnetpp;

class QKDProcessor : public cSimpleModule
{
     private:
          int randomGate;
          int counter = 0 ;
     protected:
          virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};

Define_Module(QKDProcessor);

void QKDProcessor::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
     if(strcmp("QuantumStatesProcessorBob", getName()) == 0)
     {
         delete msg;
         if(counter == 0)
         {
             cMessage *keyCheck = new cMessage("T");
             send(keyCheck,"out",0);
         }
         counter++;
     }
     else
     {
         std::string key = msg->getName();
         delete msg;
         char *stat = new char[key.length()+1];
         strcpy(stat, key.c_str());

         for(int i=0; i<key.length(); i++)
         {
             // Selecting random gates
             double x = rand()/static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX+1);
             randomGate = 0 + static_cast<int>( x * (4 - 0) );

             // Create individual message for each bit.
             std::string j = std::string(1,stat[i]);
             cMessage *quantumState = new cMessage(j.c_str());
             send(quantumState,"out", randomGate);
         }
     }
 }
```

### Module B Code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

 using namespace omnetpp;

 class PolarizationFilter : public cSimpleModule
 {
      protected:
          virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
 };

 Define_Module(PolarizationFilter);

 void PolarizationFilter::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
 {
     send(msg,"polarizaedLight",0);
 }
```

### Simulation Log

```
** Initializing network
Initializing module QKDNetwork, stage 0
QKDNetwork.AliceProcessor: Initializing module QKDNetwork.AliceProcessor, stage 0
QKDNetwork.BobProcessor: Initializing module QKDNetwork.BobProcessor, stage 0
QKDNetwork.AlicePublicChannel: Initializing module QKDNetwork.AlicePublicChannel, stage 0
QKDNetwork.BobPublicChannel: Initializing module QKDNetwork.BobPublicChannel, stage 0
QKDNetwork.FilterA: Initializing module QKDNetwork.FilterA, stage 0
QKDNetwork.FilterB: Initializing module QKDNetwork.FilterB, stage 0
QKDNetwork.FilterC: Initializing module QKDNetwork.FilterC, stage 0
QKDNetwork.FilterD: Initializing module QKDNetwork.FilterD, stage 0
QKDNetwork.Alice_Quantum_Channel: Initializing module QKDNetwork.Alice_Quantum_Channel, stage 0
QKDNetwork.Bob_Quantum_Channel: Initializing module QKDNetwork.Bob_Quantum_Channel, stage 0
QKDNetwork.DiagonalFilter: Initializing module QKDNetwork.DiagonalFilter, stage 0
QKDNetwork.HorizontalFilter: Initializing module QKDNetwork.HorizontalFilter, stage 0
QKDNetwork.QuantumStatesProcessorBob: Initializing module QKDNetwork.QuantumStatesProcessorBob, stage 0
QKDNetwork.QuantumStatesProcessorAlice: Initializing module QKDNetwork.QuantumStatesProcessorAlice, stage 0
** Event #1  t=0  QKDNetwork.QuantumStatesProcessorAlice (QKDProcessor, id=15)  on 01000001 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=0)
** Event #2  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterC (PolarizationFilter, id=8)  on 0 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=2)
** Event #3  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterB (PolarizationFilter, id=7)  on 1 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=4)
** Event #4  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterB (PolarizationFilter, id=7)  on 0 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=6)
** Event #5  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterD (PolarizationFilter, id=9)  on 0 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=8)
** Event #6  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterD (PolarizationFilter, id=9)  on 0 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=10)
** Event #7  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterC (PolarizationFilter, id=8)  on 0 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=12)
** Event #8  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterA (PolarizationFilter, id=6)  on 0 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=14)
** Event #9  t=0  QKDNetwork.FilterD (PolarizationFilter, id=9)  on 1 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=16)
** Event #10  t=0  QKDNetwork.Alice_Quantum_Channel (QKDChannel, id=10)  on 0 (omnetpp::cMessage, id=2)
```

Comment: Could you show a log from simulation as well as the C++ code of sending messages by left module? This image shows only **in which order** the messages are sent and it does not prove that middle modules send messages in different times.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jerzy, I updated the question with required information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks that A sends all messages at the same time and B immediately sends them to C. If all links between A and B (and B and C) have the same delay (or don't have any delay), C will receive all messages at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Jerzy, its working now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jerzy suggested, your simulation is working correctly. Assuming that you did not set a delay on the channel between the modules, what you are seeing is that all these message exchanges are happening at the same time (t=0) NOT in a sequence as the actual animation suggest. In the simulation time those messages are happening at the SAME time. Watch the simulation time display in the upper right corner. It does not progress during these message exchanges but stays at 0, so your assumption that Module B does not send immediately after receiving a message is false. While these message exchanges are happening at the same simulation time, the simulator serializes them for better (or worse) during animation. Or to put it differently, there are two different timelines here: Simulation time and animation time. The two are NOT the same and sometimes can be confusing.

Now, if you want to see an animation that is more in line with the simulation time you should go to the animation options dialog and enable broadcast animations. That mode gathers all events (message sends) that happen in the same *event* and animates them in parallel. You would see all the messages sent by Module A animated in parallel and right after that Module B would send to C. Note that this is still NOT mirrors the reality (simulation time) because it animates only those messages in parallel that are happening in the same event (not those that are happening at the same simulation time). i.e. In reality all the both module A and B would send the messages at the same time and all the message exchanges on the video should be animated at once. However that animation would be also misleading with the graphical implementation of message send with a dot traveling along the connection lines because in that case you would lose the cause and effect information (i.e. you would not see that message from module B is actually caused by the messages incoming from module A, so this mode would be also misleading). That's why OMNeT++ falls back to animate only messages from the same event.

A third way of animation would be to get rid of the traveling dots and just flash the connection lines showing that a message exchange occurred. This would however also lose information you would see just all the connections on the screen flashing at the same time and the cause effect relationship would be again lost.

In reality, information never travels at infinite speed between *physical* entities so some kind of delay is always justified on the channels between them. An that helps a lot with the animation. A final advice is that you should use the latest version of OMNeT++ and Qtenv as it has vastly improved animation capabilities.